# Test for 2 values in column range until bank cell is reached in different column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am attempting to test whether two values in a range exists, I am fully aware of how to achieve this, my issue is that the number of rows in the range change and I want to test until the next blank row in column E then continue to the next until another blank row is detected. I have therefore placed a match argument in Column H to count the number of rows until a blank is found.

[image]

Column G holds the data I want to argue against which itself is a lookup and therefore the blanks in the rows are not blanks, hence using column E

In column I4:I100 want to write a formula that states If value “C” AND “D” exists in column G for the next 7 rows then enter ‘Y’, then repeat the argument after the 0 in column H, for the next 6 rows and again for the next 2 rows etc etc I have manually entered my desired result in column I highlighted in green.

I hope this makes sense, Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try this in `I4` and drag down:

```
=IF(G3="",IF(AND(COUNTIF(INDEX(G:G,ROW()):INDEX(G:G,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(INDEX(G:G,ROW()):G$33="",),0)+ROW(G3)),"D")>=1,COUNTIF(INDEX(G:G,ROW()):INDEX(G:G,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(INDEX(G:G,ROW(G3)):G$33="",),0)=ROW()),"C")>=1),"Y","N"),"")
```

Now you can remove column `H:H`

Comment: organizing the formula to multiple lines (using `Alt`+`Enter`) would make it more readable.

Comment: Hi Jvd, 

Your formula works perfectly if each row in Column G was blank or empty at the end of the data set :-( Sadly as i stated earlier each row in Column G has a formula. Therefore i need another method to dictate the range. Thanks

Comment: @Prospidnick, small edit to the formula really to check for `""`. Check if it works now =)

Comment: @Prospidnick, another off topic comment: you have so many open questions. You should consider revisit them and accept/upvote answers to those who helped you out. That's a decent thing to do and would reward the ones who helped you.

Comment: Apologies @JvdV i do always thank people for their help, maybe i was ignorant to up voting, i will try harder in future.

Comment: @prospidnick, im not just talking about upvote, more about accepting answers by clicking the checkmark next to the answer to also close the question.

Comment: @JvdV I've been back over all my questions (12 in 4 years) and done as you suggested. Again apologies for being ignorant of the process :-)

Comment: I appreciate it @prospidnick